# How to load a external url in a popup or modal window in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Can you pls let me know how to load a external url in a popup or modal window in angular4? Google search seems to point towards opening in a external window or tab but I need to open as a popup or modal in my application?

Also, in the same popup, can we subscribe for url redirect? Say, I open modal and load with url http://url1 and user does something and then it redirects to http://url2, I need to be able detect that and then close that window, after extracting some info from the url2 query params. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a modal component, and give it @Input url ...http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/01/24/angular-2-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

Comment: @callback - Thanks. Can you also let me know how to subscribe for url redirect inside the modal component?

Comment: Maybe you can use an iframe inside the modal? and when the change happens just change the url of the iframe? Or do you want this to happen without reloading the modal page?

Comment: Reloading modal should be ok. For using @Input url, can you share some code sample? Sorry, am bit new to angular. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You know what an input is? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.. Basically, `@Input() url: string;` that will be passed in the parent template to the modal child component.

Comment: @callback - sorry, if I was not clear. I tried setting that, but the contents of the url must be loaded into the modal. I tried using normal http to load the contents, on ngInit, but it does not. So I wanted to see if there is some sample snippet for the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165984/discussion-between-csharpnewbie-and-callback).